# UIView in UITableview, working with 3,5 inch and 4inch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I'm trying to display a `UIView` inside a `UITableview`. This `view` must recover the whole `UITableview` during the process.

My app has the following layout:

[image: Home layout]

As you see, I use a storyboard for my app. But since I have several tabs, with one tableview per tab, I have decided to use a nib file for this single view, and display it programmatically over each `UITableview`.

The main problem is that I don't know how to display it correctly for 3,5 inch AND 4 inch devices.

I would like to have this render, regardless of the device:

[image]

The view should be under the top bar, and over the bottom bar.

But else is too short for 4 inch, else is too big 3,5 inch (and my view is no longer centered).

I have been playing with constraints for the past 2 hours, searching on google, and I have not found the correct way to do what I want to do...

I can of course do it programmatically and check the content size and apply it to my view, but can I do it without this using autolayout?

Thanks in advance.

Edit here are my constraints:

(Two tries)
[image: try1]
[image: try2]

Comment: How do you set the frame for the tableView?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I guess I don't do it programmatically. The tableview is handled by the storyboard.

I have no problem with the tableview in itself, only with the size of the view I want to put on the tableview. I can of course change the size when the tableview loads (with the contentsize), but is there a proper way to do it?

Comment: do you use addSubview or presentViewController to show the tableView?

Comment: Not for the tableview, only for the view I'm trying to display (`[self.tableView addSubview:myView]`)

Comment: Have you added proper constraints in your nib?

Comment: try this.     self.tblView.contentMode = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill;

Comment: I have tried to add constraints to superview (50 and 65, size of top bar and bottom bar) but it's not working

Comment: @Bejibun StackOverflow is not the right place to throw things at the wall and see if they stick. Your answer and your comment are not close to what the issue here might be nor do they try to know more about the issue.

Comment: You are not setting up your constraints properly. Show us how you add your constraints and what constraints you actually use.

Comment: @duci9y, I'm trying to help and the issue can be in a million possibilities.

Comment: Did you check or uncheck Use Autolayout?

Comment: Thanks all for your help. I have added a screenshot of what I have tried for my constraints in the main post.

The first one means for me, "take the space you have", the second one "Take the space you have after top bar and bottom bar".

I'm using autolayout.

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show the constraints for the 'container view'.

Comment: Sorry, it has been updated :-)